# How to remove first word of sentence and replace by another?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, replace

I am having multiple paragraphs which were coming in loop dynamically. I just want to add a prefix to those paragraphs after checking that a paragraph's first word contains a keyword I am looking for.

I tried many times yet I am unable to get a perfect answer.

```
$var="Hello, this paragraph is a series of related sentences developing a central idea, called the topic. Try to think idea.";
if (stripos($var, 'hello,') !== false) {
echo 'true';
}
```

Please help with this. I received many similar, related answers but I didn't get the expected one. I am looking to make it work with with case-insensitive.

Comment: The problem may be that you are looking for `hello.` which has a `.` at the end, the text you are searching has a `,` at the end of `Hello,`.

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen  .. but problem was to replace hello with another word.

Comment: Replace `(stripos($var, 'hello.') !== false)`  with `(stripos($var, 'hello') !== 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if understand your question right, but maybe you can try this.

```
$var = "Hello, this paragraph is a series of related sentences developing a central idea, called the topic. Try to think idea.";

if (stripos($var, 'hello,') === 0) {
    // this checks if the searched word is exactly at the beginning of the string
    $var = 'YOUR PREFIX -- ' . $var;
}

echo $var;
```

If you want to replace the first word, then you should use that code.

```
$var = "Hello, this paragraph is a series of related sentences developing a central idea, called the topic. Try to think idea.";

if (stripos($var, 'hello,') === 0) {
    // this checks if the searched word is exactly at the beginning of the string
    $var = preg_replace('/hello\,/i', 'REPLACE WITH', $var, 1);
}

echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strpos`

```
if(strpos($var, 'Hello,') === 0 || strpos($var, 'hello,') === 0){
  //Your Logic
}
```